# Identical objects but different types

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

I use a C++ app to synchronyze data between two PHP servers.

My first server is local, my C++ app call a webservice on that server to get an object to synchronyze. Then, my C++ app use another webservice to send it on my Cloud PHP server.

So my Object is a soap object defined strictly identically on my two php server.

However, for my C++ apps, these two object are not the same (or at least with a different namespace), so Y can't compile the following line:

```
soapErrorCode = cloudWebService.action(myLocalObject);
//C++ is waiting for an object of type myCloudObject, even if these two object have the same attributes
```

My soap objects and Webservice definition are defined in my C++ with help of gSoap.

I see different solution, but not sure which is the best:

1. Is there a way to tell to C++ that myLocalObject and myCloudObject are the same? Note: I don't want manually modify the code generated by gsoap (too much work!).
2. Is there a way to tell to gsoap that myLocalObject and myCloudObject are the same?
3. Am I obliged to create fonction to convert myLocalObject to myCloudObject?

Thanks!

Comment: if there are 2 types different, yes you have to write in some ways the conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion two possible variants are:

1. Write converter function from `myLocalObject` to `myCloudObject` and from from `myCloudObject` to `myLocalObject`
2. You can make a base class for `myLocalObject` and `myCloudObject` and work through its pointer.

Comment: Ok, I will go on the converter function. It adds lot of code but easy code, so it's better than modifying code generated by gsoap.